# State Error. Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, state

I have a task to merge to components in state.js in Angular. I am pretty new in this. I had included the code and it is throwing state error which I am unable to understand from where it is coming. I think I did correctly but something is missing that I unable to understand.

This is the error : -

```
error: Could not resolve 'auth.app' from state 'auth'
    at Object.x.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at Object.x.go (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at angular-ui-router.min.js:7
    at angular.js:16299
    at e (angular.js:4924)
    at angular.js:5312
```

I had gone through other answers too but couldn't find my solution. 
**my state.js :-**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

       $urlRouterProvider
                .when('/home', '/')
                .otherwise('/');
       $stateProvider
// Applications (parent state)
                .state('auth.apps', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '/applications',
                    template: '<div ui-view autoscroll="false" class="mainView-animate"></div>',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: 'Applications'
                    }
                })
                // Applications childs
                .state("auth.apps.view", {
                    // this state page title
                    page_title: 'New - Applications',
                    // this state url
                    url: "/apps",
                    templateUrl: 'views/externals/apps.html',
                    // load state specific js/css
                    resolve: {
                        files: [
                            'uiLoad',
                            function (uiLoad) {
                                return uiLoad.load([
                                    // c3 charts
                                    'assets/lib/d3/d3.min.js',
                                    'assets/lib/c3/c3.min.js'                         
                                ]);
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    controller: 'AppCtrl',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: 'Applications'
                    }
                })

                .state('auth.apps.create', {
                    page_title: 'New - Create',
                    url: '/create',
                    templateUrl: 'views/externals/connect_vm.html',
                    resolve: {
                        files: [
                            'uiLoad',
                            function (uiLoad) {
                                return uiLoad.load([
                                    // select2
                                    'assets/lib/select2/select2.css',
                                    'assets/lib/select2/select2.min.js',                                  
                                    // inputmask
                                    'assets/lib/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js'

                                ]);
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    controller: 'AddCtrl',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: 'Connect'
                    }
                })


                .state('auth.apps.validate', {
                    page_title: 'New - Validate',
                    url: '/validate',
                    templateUrl: 'views/externals/cluster_validation_vm.html',
                    resolve: {
                        VMsData: function(VMsList){
                            var vms_data = VMsList.getList();
                            return vms_data;
                        },
                        files: [
                            'uiLoad',
                            function (uiLoad) {
                                return uiLoad.load([
                                    // select2
                                    'assets/lib/select2/select2.css',
                                    'assets/lib/select2/select2.min.js'                              
                                ]);
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    controller: 'ValidateCtrl',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: 'Validations'
                    }
                })
 }
]);
```

Comment: you don't have any state with a name `'auth.app'`, maybe you misspelled it try changing  `'auth.app'` to `'auth.apps'`

Comment: @AmayaSan its `auth.apps` only. But from where `auth.app` info is coming that I am not getting that.

Comment: well could you provide a certain scenario on where the error will occurred

Comment: @AmayaSan Didn't get you.

Comment: At what certain scenario it will occur? ex: clicking a link, etc...

Comment: @AmayaSan yes on clicking one of the side menu option list.

Comment: Well could you provide the html file

Comment: @AmayaSan Yes , you were right the error is from HTML page. But I am unable to figure out which html file as there is many partial html files. How to check on Chrome console ?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot on where it occurs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169510/discussion-between-whoami-and-amaya-san).

Answer (score 1):

The cause if the error is `auth.apps` is abstract you cannot navigate into an abstract route.

```
 .state('auth.apps', {
                    //abstract: true, <-- remove this
                    url: '/applications',
                    template: '<div ui-view autoscroll="false" class="mainView-animate"></div>',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: 'Applications'
                    }
                })
```